# How to quick reply with Google Hangouts on iOS 10?

Tags: notifications, ios, google-hangouts

On iOS 9 I would utilize the [quick reply functionality](http://lifehacker.com/hangouts-for-ios-improves-notification-support-adds-qu-1745487752) to reply to Google Hangout messages. However, since upgrading to iOS 10 I am no longer able to use quick reply as a swipe left on a Hangout notification only gives the option to clear.

Is there an iOS 10 setting that I need to enable for Hangouts to be able to quick reply? Or is this something that Google needs to change with Hangouts to accommodate iOS 10's new notification APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiping left now universally gives the option to clear notifications.

Apps that haven't been explicitly updated for iOS 10 should still reveal their current swipe options by long-pressing (iPhone 6 and earlier) or 3D touching (iPhone 6s and later) on the notification.

I just received a notification via Google Hangouts and upon 3D touching on the notification on my iPhone 7 lock screen, I got two options as seen in the first screenshot (Reply and View). Tapping Reply presented me with the quick reply screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should and do are often different. ;-)

Comment: Have you tried it? I just now received a notification from Google Hangouts and have updated the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Had not used 3D Touch. Rereading your answer I now understand what you meant. I agree that 3D Touch does work for bringing up Reply and View. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a change that Google needs to make for their apps.  It's not something that Apple can fix inside the Google app.

Google might've moved this function or made it a 3D Touch feature, I don't know.

Comment: I assumed it would require a fix from Google to accommodate Apple API changes for iOS 10, but wanted to be sure I wasn't missing some obscure OS setting.